# Google Cloud Platform centos machine keeps booting off

Tags: centos7, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have an issue with a centos GCP machine, which keeps booting off after a period of 1-2 days:

[pic of the lost session to the machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5kSN.png)

I am new to GCP and was wondering what can I do to fix this.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Why do you have to hold an SSH connection open for 1-2 days with no activity?

Comment: I am using this machine to host an asp.net core app for testing purposes, after 1-2 days the server is down and the machine seem to have rebooted

Comment: If you SSH into the server and run `uptime`, what is the result?

Comment: good point, it says up for 52 days meaning that the machine it self is not shutting down but this possibly has something to do with the session disconnects

Comment: I guess I need to run: "sudo dotnet run" not in a context of a ssh session

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, the server is not rebooting - the SSH connection is being dropped, which although an SSH connection should theoretically last indefinitely, it will be at the mercy of network connectivity and various other factors that are not within your control.

If you have an app which is running over SSH, I'd seriously consider looking into converting the application to run as a service, or at the very least launching the application from within `screen`.

There are various mechanisms you can use to do this, depending on your application architecture, its runtime requirements and your OS.

Comment: Thanks man that is really helpful!